# Рассчитать максимально возможный размер массива (кол-во элементов), который не приведет к наполнению памяти

Tags: массивы, динамические-массивы, структуры-данных

Создан динамически расширяющийся массив, состоящий из 1000 элементов, размер 4 Б. На диске для изменения массива доступно 100 000 Б. Напишите максимально возможный размер массива(кол-во элементов), который не приведет к переполнению памяти. Максимально возможный размер массива рассчитайте исходя из того, что при необходимости размер массива удваивается.
Изначально я подумал, что ответ 24000 элементов(96к байт), но меня смутило последнее предложение, что это вообще значит?

Comment: Каждое следующее значение получается как текущее, умноженное на 2. Получаем 1000, 2000, 4000, 8000, 16000. Однако, тут надо учесть, можем ли мы получить новый массив путем расширения (с конца) текущего (модель, которую может использовать Си realloc) или обязаны выделять для вего него новую память (модель С++ new). В последнем случае получите максимум 8000. К этому моменту будут заняты 15000 (вместе с последним размером 8000) из 25000 (на новые 16000 места уже нет)

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял условие, увеличивать массив вы можете только удвоением его размера.

Т.е. берёте начальный размер массива и последовательно удваиваете его до тех пор, пока получается размер не более заданного максимума. Вот последний размер, не превосходящий максимум, и будет решением задачи.

Comment: Зависит от модели (realloc или new) расширения массива

Comment: @avp Мне кажется, это слишком сложно для учебной задачи. Но мысль полезная, конечно